# Error comando desconocido: tipo "make"

Tags: python, django

Cuando ejecuto el siguiente comando desde linea de comandos

```
C:\master-python\22-django\AprendiendoDjango>python manage.py make migration
```

Me figura este error en el cmd:

> Unknown command: 'make' Type
> 'manage.py help' for usage.

¿Qué puede estar mal?

Comment: Por qué la etiqueta sql?

Comment: En el directorio en donde se encuentra el archivo manage.py debes ejecutar el comando `python manage.py makemigrations` (OJO: `makemigrations` no `make migration`).

Comment: Te traduzco el error: > Comando "make" no reconocido. Escribe 'manage.py help' para ves los usos posibles [Documentación oficial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/)

Comment: Los comandos validos son: `makemigrations` o `migrate`

Comment: muchisimas gracias Firefly y ariel montes lo descubri despues , muy agradecido por la ayuda . soy nuevo en este mundo de la programacion